# Advanced Find & Replace / Text Expand / Macros

Tags: macros, komodo, komodoedit

Hopefully a nice quick one for someone. I'm working on a project that requires a specific link being written around 400 or so locations. Each link is the same, except it has the town's name in it, such as:

```
<li><a href="/contact-details.html?location=Andover">Andover</a></li>
```

I'm currently using Komodo Edit to write my projects, and I have Zen Coding installed and a decent knowledge of the built-in Snippets functionality.

I know that using Snippets, I could create the link above from the word Andover in a key-binding, but as far as I know only one line at a time.

I also know that I could use Zen Coding to get to the stage of:

```
<li><a href="/contact-details.html?location=">Andover</a></li>
```

but without the location name in the link by using wrap with abbreviation and

```
li*>a[href=/contact-details.html?location=]
```

Obviously both of these still leave quite a lot of work to do, and I'm sure it's possible with a Komodo macro but I don't know enough about them to do that.

Does anyone know of a way in Komodo, or using Zen Coding, or any website or application, that can do this kind of slightly more advanced find/replace / text-expansion? I've seen a few applications that do find and replace but they all base themselves around multiple files and that's a bit much for what I need.

Ideally, so I can write things like

```
<li><a href="/contact-details.html?location=[%contentOfCurrentLine]">[%contentOfCurrentLine]</a></li>
```

and replicate it over all 400 locations in one go.

Comment: You may have a better chance of getting a response at the official Komodo forum: http://community.activestate.com/forums/komodo-support

Answer (score 0):

Use a snippet like this named 'ListLink':

```
<li><a href="/contact-details.html?location=[[%W]]">[[%W]]</a></li>
```

And create a macro using the [scimoz](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/6.1/macroapi.html#macroapi_scimoz) and [projects](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/6.1/macroapi.html#macroapi_findPart) APIs to move the cursor and call the snippet in a loop:

```
komodo.assertMacroVersion(2);
if (komodo.view && komodo.view.scintilla) { komodo.view.scintilla.focus(); }

var i = 1;
var len = ko.views.manager.currentView.scimoz.lineCount; /* Count lines */
_part = ko.projects.findPart('snippet', 'ListLink', '*'); /* Find Snippet*/
ko.views.manager.currentView.scimoz.documentStart(); /* goto first line */

while (i <= len)
  {
  if (!_part) {alert("Couldn't find a snippet called 'ListLink' when executing macro."); return;}
  ko.projects.invokePart(_part); /* invoke Snippet */
  ko.views.manager.currentView.scimoz.lineDown(); /* goto next line */
  i++;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in **Komode**.

1. Go to "**Edit**" ( in top menu), "**Find**".
2. Will open a window, check the chackbox "**Replace**" (or others that you need)
3. Complete the text fields "**find what**" and "**replace with**", them click "**Replace All**"

Just it!